# Reverse relationship for OneToOneField Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using User model

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

UserProfile model extends User model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofiles')
    avatar = models.FileField('img',upload_to='./static/image/')
```

I need to take user's avatar, I am doing something like

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

user.userprofiles
```

But it throws me error

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile.

Trace:

```
In [5]: user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

In [6]: user.userprofiles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2253b19e792d> in <module>()
----> 1 user.userprofiles

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_des
criptors.py in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    405                 "%s has no %s." % (
    406                     instance.__class__.__name__,
--> 407                     self.related.get_accessor_name()
    408                 )
    409             )

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofiles.
```

Comment: Thanks all for your effort. I am creating user while signup but i am not creating userprofile. Now i am able to get user.userprofiles for all users

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in the following:

```
 user   = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofiles')
 # userprofiles with 's'
```

Whereas, you have tried to have access to it with `user.userprofile` without s

Either you remove the `s` in the `related_name='userprofiles'`, or add `s`: --> *user.userprofiles* to access the `Userprofile`.

Comment: what's the error ? please run `makemigrations` & `migrate` if you changed the related_name

Comment: post the 3 last lines of the traceback in comments

Comment: criptors.py in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    405                 "%s has no %s." % (
    406                     instance.__class__.__name__,
--> 407                     self.related.get_accessor_name()
    408                 )
    409             )

Comment: what did you do, please? can you edit your question with your current with it, also the full traceback

Comment: I could say, it's not an issue at all, you only get the issue because `User` doesn't have a `UserProfile` instance

Answer (score 0):

To get the `UserProfile` object from the `User` object, you need to use `userprofiles`

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
up = user.userprofiles
up.user == user    # will return True
```

Answer (score -2):

You just don't have UserProfile for that User in database. 
`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` says by itself)